# Rails nil errors - any way to stop them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I've been learning Rails for the past 6 months.  I think it's great!

But, 99% of errors my app gets are nil errors.  I'm either trying to display a field that is nil or a foreign key is pointing to a record that has been deleted.

I have this type of code in many places:

```
        <% if location.parent != nil %>
          <td><%= location.parent.name %></td>
        <% else %>
          <td></td>
        <% end %>

      <% if location.client_id != nil %>
        <td><%= location.client.client_name %></td>
      <% else %>
        <td></td>
      <% end %>
```

I really wish Rails would just show a blank when the field is nil!  Or, set a flash with an error and still show the page.  Instead, the page bombs.  On Heroku, you get the "Sorry, somethings wrong...."

Is there any way to better handle blank fields? Is there a better way to code the above?  Is there some Rails setting I'm not aware of?  Is there a gem to handle these type of errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really place some [foreign key constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#active-record-and-referential-integrity) and [after_destroy methods on your associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks). This will stop your database getting into a inconsistant state.

But aside from that refactor you should checkout ActiveSupport and the various additions it makes to ruby. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html.

There are three methods which are available on any object which I think would be helpful to you:

- `blank?` - Returns true if the object is nil, empty?, false and other conditions. See [the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#blank-and-present) for a better explanation.
- `present?` - Returns true if the object is not nil, not empty? or true. See [the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#blank-and-present) for a better explanation.
- `try(:foo)` - Attempts to call the method `foo` on the object, returns nil if the object is nil. See [the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#try) for a better explanation.

With this your sample code could be:

```
<td><%= location.parent.try(:name) %></td>
<td><%= location.parent.try(:client_name) %></td>
```

I would really recommend that you have a look at why you are expecting an object to not be nil. [Foreign key constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#active-record-and-referential-integrity) in your migration and [after_destroy hooks for your associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks) will help with this.

Comment: Thanks - I will investigate your suggestions further.

Comment: I think you should also explain the benefits of the safe navigation operator. as opposed to `try`

Comment: Fair comment - though when I answered this question ruby 2.3 wasn't released (two years before the release!). TBH I personally try to avoid using `try` or `&.` as it leads to code with insufficient guard clauses or ignoring Law of Demeter.

Answer (score 0):

Not a Rails fix, but you can use the NullObject pattern of object oriented design to refactor your code to handle "nil" differently. The pattern basically means that you create a null/nil class for an object that handles when it is nil. It has some downsides: an extra class to maintain and you have to remember to edit the null class when you add new methods which may be nil. The good is that it moves the conditionals out of the view.

Here's a good blog post on the subject:
http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/20907555103/rails-refactoring-example-introduce-null-object

Another suggestion would be to move the conditionals out of your view and into helpers. Helpers are simple modules that contain view logic. I've suffered through views with all their logic in the view and it makes the view code a mess very quickly.